# Use an External ResourceDictionary in a WindowsPhone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to create an ResourceFile Called DataTemplate.xaml in an external dll and use that in a WP7 page.  When I do the following in the header of my Page I get an error

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WP7SharedClassLibrary;component/DataTemplate.xaml" />`

The error is
"Current project does not support 'application' as the authority component of the pack URI."

Has anyone else come across this and solved this?

Answer (score 13):

I've managed to get this to work using the following steps:

1. Created a standard WP7 application using the "Windows Phone Application" application template called "WP7ExternalResourcesTest".
2. Added a project to the same solution using the "Windows Phone Class Library" template called "WP7ExternalResourcesTestLibrary".
3. Removed the default Class.cs file form the library project.
4. Added a file called "External.xaml" using the "XML file" template and set the "Build Action" to "Page".
5. Added the following XAML to the new XAML file:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Red" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
6. Built the library project, and then added a reference to it from the WP7ExternalResourcesTest project.
7. In WP7ExternalResourcesTest, opened App.xaml and changed the `Application.Resources` section to the following:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="/WP7ExternalResourcesTestLibrary;component/External.xaml" />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
8. In MainPage.xaml, added `Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"` to the `TextBlock` named "PageTitle".
9. Ran the application in the emulator. The end result was that the `TextBlock` correctly displayed the words "page name" in red.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doh! Looks like I forgot step 6 :-( In my case I had to reference not only the external project but also the WP_Utilities.DLL from another project that the external project was based on. Thanks for the detailed write up!

Comment: Additionally, I've just discovered that WP8 doesn't like having a period in the referenced assembly name. If you're having trouble getting it to work, that could be your issue.

Comment: so do you really need to put the ResourceDictionary in a separate assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the pack syntax while trying to share XAML ResourceDictionary files and got the same error message. I ended up using this syntax and it worked for me.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyDLLName;component/Folder/MyXAMLFile.xaml"/>                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Gives "Attribute /WP_Utilities;component/Resources/PerformanceProgressBar.xaml value is out of range. [Line: 17 Position: 37]
   --- Inner Exception ---
KeyNotFoundException" error at runtime. What is the build type of your MyXAMLFile.xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't support pack URIs. It's a WPF feature.

If you examine the type of the `Source` property for the `Image` object in Silverlight it is `Uri`. But in WPF the source is a dependency property with a type of `ImageSource.`