# What is Best Practice for storing texts of elements such TextBlock in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have many elements that have texts and I want to centralize it all in one place. Maybe in the future it will help me if I'll decide to change from english to other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Localizing a Windows Phone app step by step.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Localizing-a-Windows-Phone-app-Step-by-Step)

It's pretty straight forward, you create a Resource file and enter your strings there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource dictionary to store your texts.

[All about Resource Dictionary in WP7](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-ResourceDictionary-in-WP7)

[External Resource Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875265/use-an-external-resourcedictionary-in-a-windowsphone-7-app)